# Error using trigger in Oracle sql

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bi_payregister
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON payregister
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT helloabc.NEXTVAL INTO :new.id FROM DUAL;
END
```

what is wrong with this statement, it shows error.I have created PAYREGISTER table and HelloABC sequence already.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: Error(2,58): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the syntax error that your code produces, you're missing the semi-colon (and forward slash) off the end of the "END". It should be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bi_payregister
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON payregister
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT helloabc.NEXTVAL INTO :new.id FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```